# build gradle returns appears with kts extension

Tags: android, build.gradle

I recently updated my Android studio to Canary11 version and when I created a new java project, I just discovered that the build.gradles is having kts extension and as it stands, I cannot be able to add any other external dependencies apart from the firebase own that I added directly from the IDE. I don't know why it's appearing like that and I really need help on how to solve it. These is how it's.

```
    build.gradle.kts(app)
    
    @Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
    plugins {
        alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
        id("com.google.gms.google-services")
    }
    
    android {
        namespace = "com.elijahukeme.quizapp"
        compileSdk = 34
    
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId = "com.elijahukeme.quizapp"
            minSdk = 21
            targetSdk = 34
            versionCode = 1
            versionName = "1.0"
    
            testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
    
        buildTypes {
            release {
                isMinifyEnabled = false
                proguardFiles(
                    getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                    "proguard-rules.pro"
                )
            }
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
    
        implementation(libs.appcompat)
        implementation(libs.material)
        implementation(libs.constraintlayout)
        implementation(libs.firebase.auth)
        implementation(libs.firebase.database)
        implementation(libs.firebase.firestore)
        implementation(libs.firebase.storage)
        testImplementation(libs.junit)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.test.ext.junit)
        androidTestImplementation(libs.espresso.core)
    }
    
    build.gradle.kts(project)
    
    buildscript {
        dependencies {
            classpath(libs.google.services)
        }
    }
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
    @Suppress("DSL_SCOPE_VIOLATION") // TODO: Remove once KTIJ-19369 is fixed
    plugins {
        alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication) apply false
    }
    true // Needed to make the Suppress annotation work for the plugins block
    
    
    these are the dependencies that I wanted to add
    def nav_version = "2.7.5"
    
        // Java language implementation
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version"
        implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version"
```

Comment: " I cannot be able to add any other external dependencies apart from the firebase own that I added directly from the IDE" -- Gradle supports both Groovy (`build.gradle`) and Kotlin (`build.gradle.kts`) for its build scripts. Gradle supports dependencies using both languages. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/build/dependencies), which covers both `build.gradle` and `build.gradle.kts`.

Comment: I have gone through the documentation and it's still not giving me scope on how to add new dependencies because the way the .kts appears is a bit strange to me and I cannot be able to add any new dependency and I will also like to know if there is a way that I can revert it to the normal build.gradle that I am used to @CommonsWare

Comment: You are certainly welcome to replace the `build.gradle.kts` files with equivalent `build.gradle` files. For example, you might copy them from some older project. Or, you might consider moving back to the stable version of Android Studio, rather than the Canary build, as Giraffe still uses Groovy build scripts by default. Or, you might see if the Canary build new-project wizard gives you a choice of Groovy or Kotlin build scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're seeing is Gradle version catalog: [Android developers docs](https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-catalogs), [Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html). This can be used with both Kotlin and Groovy build scripts.

You should be able to mix dependencies added directly and via version catalog with no problems, though you'll need to use Kotlin syntax in `.kts` files:

```
dependencies {
    val nav_version = "2.7.5"
    
    // Java language implementation
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:$nav_version")
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:$nav_version")
}
```

Or you can add your dependencies to the version catalog in `gradle/libs.versions.toml`:

```
[versions]
nav_version = "2.7.5"

[libraries]
androidx-navigation-fragment = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment", version.ref = "nav_version" }
androidx-navigation-ui = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-ui", version.ref = "nav_version" }
```

and then reference them in `build.gradle.kts`

```
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.fragment)
    implementation(libs.androidx.navigation.ui)
    // or use the automatic grouping
    // implementation(libs.androidx.navigation)
}
```